# Similarity transformation and representation of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices, companion-matrices

I'm trying to understand this passage of a book:

[image]

[image]

Why this last expressions shows that the $i$th column of $\bar{A}$ is the representation of $Aq_i$ with respect to the basis $\{q_1,\ldots q_n\}$? I can't understand how the author reached this conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach may help.  I believe if you explicitly extract out the $i$'th column of the left hand side and compare to $Q$ multiplying the $i$'th column of $\bar{A}$ on the right hand side, you will see the claim.

For example, let $i=1$, then we have:

$$
A\mathbf{q}_{1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{q}_{1} & \mathbf{q}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{q}_{n} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \bar{A}_{11} \\
\bar{A}_{21} \\
\vdots  \\
\bar{A}_{n1} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
A\mathbf{q}_{1} = 
\bar{A}_{11} \mathbf{q}_{1} + \bar{A}_{21}\mathbf{q}_{2} + \ldots + \bar{A}_{n1}\mathbf{q}_{n}
$$

I hope this helps.